# Алгоритмы! Правильно ли я делаю?

Tags: алгоритм, pascal

Есть код

```
S:=0; 
For i:=1 to n*2 do 
  begin s:=s+A[i];
  For j:=1 to n - 2 do 
    begin s:=s+A[j]; 
    For k:=1 to n-3 do 
      s:=s+A[k]; 
  end; 
end;
For m:=1 to n - 4 do 
  s:=s+A[m];
```

И я хочу вычислить сколько раз я буду изменять s (присваивать новое значение).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне кажется, что я не прав, поэтому просьба ко всем знающим указать на мои ошибки и посоветовать какие-нибудь материалы для решения подобных задач

p.s А еще я не знаю, как раскрывать такие сигмы, такие дела((

p.s.2 Я пропустил первый цикл, но не обращайте внимания))

Comment: У вас получается O(1)+O(n)+O(n^2)+O(n)=O(n^2)

Comment: Так, я немного запутался, поэтому, с Вашего позволения, я попытаюсь разобраться. O-большое - верхняя граница для вычисления временной сложности(если не так, то поправьте), разве O(n^2)  - будет формулой в общем виде для получения числа операций? Просто насколько мне известно, то она отбрасывает все коэффициенты и берет старшую степень, а мне (лично мое мнение, могу ошибаться) нужна формула целиком (со всеми коэффициентами и прочими прелюдиями)

Comment: @Harry это по формуле. В коде O(n^3).

Comment: Кажется вы не учли цикл For i:=1 to n*2 do

Comment: и почему нельзя это сначала разделить по циклам, получить что-то духе суммирования всего массива ну и умножить на что надо. Сложность O(n)

Comment: @Igor Честно говоря, не понял?...

Comment: @Harry В коде у автора - три вложенных цикла.

Comment: @Igor А! дошло :) Я почему-то решил, что вы имеете в виду - если реализовать формулу, то реальный код будет O(n^3). Да, я смотрел только на формулу, на код даже не глянул :(

Comment: Товарищи, спасибо, вроде начинаю понимать, пойду дальше грызть гранит науки! Всем хорошего настроения!

Comment: Что такое `(|)`?

Comment: Это единица у меня такая)